# How to add your own icon to a dockerhub image

Tags: dockerhub, kitematic

When opening kitematic, you get a nice overview of recommended and popular Docker images, each of those with its own app icon, etc.

[image: kitematic_recommended]

My question is, where you can set this "branding" properties in the dockerhub (icon and side color...)